# Op-Amp as an error detector

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, amplifier

[image]

In the design of an AC servo position flight control surface system, a feedback system compares the output position to the pilot's input command signal.

How is an operational amplifier used as an error detector?

Comment: Imagine where does the output go?

Comment: Error detector or error amplifier?

Comment: Came across  a block diagram and it said it used an op-amp as an error detector. Not sure if he meant error amplifier or an opamp can actually be used as an error detector

Comment: What if the servo has inertia and overshoots the target?  Can you change anything in the Op Amp to anticipate and prevent that?

Comment: Ignoring inertia

Comment: Show the block diagram you came across.

Comment: Have added the diagram

Comment: That's not a diagram. Wrong image?

Comment: Was probably wrong to say diagram, but this was the overall system for the control system

Comment: From what I know, the op-amp is supposed to amplify the error signal

Comment: It needs a block diagram Beatrice, why don't you try and draw one and we'll help you fix it up until it makes sense.

Comment: [To subtract a signal from another](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html). See the section titled differential amplifier. What you want is probably the Unity Gain differential amplifier.